# Analyzing programs

Tags: algorithm, analytics

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me the semantics of analyzing programs. I get how to do simple ones, but there are some more complicated ones I am not sure how to do. For example here is a question from my book. We are given 6 little segments of code and told to analyze them:

```
(1).  sum = 0;
      for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
          ++sum;

(2).  sum = 0;
      for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
          for( j = 0; j < n; ++j )
              ++sum;

(3).  sum = 0;
      for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
          for( j = 0; j < n * n; ++j )
              ++sum;

(4).  sum = 0;
      for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
          for( j = 0; j < i; ++j )
              ++sum;

(5).  sum = 0;
      for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
          for( j = 0; j < i * i; ++j )
              for( k = 0; k < j; ++k )
                  ++sum;

(6).  sum = 0;
      for( i = 1; i < n; ++i )
          for( j = 1; j < i * i; ++j )
              if( j % i == 0 )
                  for( k = 0; k < j; ++k )
                      ++sum;
```

I understand 1, 2, and 4. Those ones are easy. The ones I don't get are 3, 5, and 6.

1 runs `n` times so that one is in `Big-Oh(n)`. 2 has two `for` loops which both run `n` times each so this one is `Big-Oh(n^2)`. 4 is something I have seen before. The inner loop runs as many times as the value of `i`. So if `i = 1` then loop runs once, if `i = 2` the loop runs twice for a patters of `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` which is the pattern `n(n + 1) / 2` which means this whole this is in `Big-Oh(n^2)`. I am unsure how to go about 3 with the `n * n` in the conditional. That is also the reason I am not sure how to go about 5 with the `i * i` also in there. As for 6, not only do we have the `i * i` but there is also an `if` statement that may or may not run. What do I do with that? Can anyone help explain how to do those ones? Thanks.

**UPDATE** I had an idea about 3. The outer for loop in that one runs `n` times, the inner for loop runs `n^2` times. So for that one, would we have `n * n^2` which is `n^3`? So would that one be in `Big-Oh(n^3)`?

Comment: Do not ask 3 different questions in one. Ask one, learn from the answer, if you can't get it ask another one

Comment: Why ask three separate questions and take up more space on the question board? If you don't like this, then go on to the next question.

Comment: because there are rules here and one of the rules is not to ask many questions in one question. Read carefully, I have not told you pollute the site with 3 questions simultaneously. They are all similar, so ask one, wait for the answer, read try to understand. Approach your next question with the knowledge you just got

Answer (score 0):

You figured third one out. The same reasoning applies to all of them. Actually your aim is to find the final value of `sum` in terms of `n`.

For the fifth one, that is to find the sum: ∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>n</sup>(∑<sub>j=0</sub><sup>n^2</sup> (j))

The inner summation is just (i<sup>2</sup>*(i<sup>2</sup> + 1)) / 2, which is follows from [the simple summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Then you have ∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>n</sup>(i<sup>2</sup>*(i<sup>2</sup> + 1)) / 2 which is equal to [∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>n</sup>(i<sup>4</sup>) + ∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>n</sup>(i<sup>2</sup>)] / 2.

This is O(N<sup>5</sup>) looking at the dominating term ∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>n</sup>(i<sup>4</sup>), which you can think as an integral so you just increase the exponent and you get N<sup>5</sup>. Sixth one is left as an exercise, just imagine what `sum` will be in the end.